# GTest cannot load imported share library

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, shared-libraries, googletest

I am trying to use a few imported shared libraries in a project which is to be tested through GTest. If I create test executables manually (e.g. without GTest), everything works fine. However, when enabling executables that rely on GTest, the build crashes with the following error:

> ```
> <path to build dir>/test_gtest: error while loading shared libraries: ./libDependencyL2.so: >cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:112 (message):
>  Error running test executable.
>    Path: '<path to build dir>/test_gtest/test_gtest'
>    Result: 127
>    Output:
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>    /usr/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:225 (gtest_discover_tests_impl)
> ```

I am using CMake as the build system. Compilation and running take place on a x86 Ubuntu 20.04.

## Project structure

My directory structure is:

```
test_project/
    CMakeLists.txt
    src/
        test_handcrafted/
            CMakeLists.txt
            test_handcrafted.cpp
        test_gtest/
            CMakeLists.txt
            test_gtest.cpp
        test_utils
            CMakeLists.txt
            test_utils.cpp
            test_utils.hpp
    lib/
        libTarget.so
        Target.hpp
        libDependencyLevel1.so
        DependencyLevel1.hpp
        libDependencyLevel2.so
        DependencyLevel2.hpp
    build/
```

`libTarget.so` contains the functionalities to be verified. `libDependencyLevel1.so` contains utils for visualizing test outputs and it depends on `libDependencyLevel2.so`. `test_utils` contains all functions and classes that are actually called by the tests.

For instance, the command `$ldd libDependencyLevel1.so` returns:

> ```
> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff17bb6000)
> libDependencyLevel2.so => not found
> libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe5f3357000)
> libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe5f333c000)
> libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe5f314a000)
> libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe5f2ffb000)
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe5f358d000)
> ```

## Build system

**test_project/CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(MY_TEST)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(ExternalProject)

add_library(libTarget SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libTarget PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libTarget.so"
)

add_library(libDependencyLevel2 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libDependencyLevel2 PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libDependencyLevel2.so"
)

add_library(libDependencyLevel1 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libDependencyLevel2 PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libDependencyLevel2.so"
)
add_dependencies(libDependencyLevel1 libDependencyLevel2)


include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    googletest
    URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)

set(MY_LIBRARIES_HEADERS_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test_utils)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test_handcrafted)
# add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test_gtest) # UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE CAUSES BUILD ERROR
```

**src/test_utils/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_library(test_utils test_utils.cpp)

target_include_directories(test_utils PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    MY_LIBRARIES_HEADERS_DIR
)

target_link_libraries(test_utils PUBLIC libTarget libDependencyLevel1 libDependencyLevel2)
```

**src/test_handcrafted/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(test_handcrafted test_handcrafted.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test_handcrafted PRIVATE libTarget test_utils)
```

**src/test_gtest/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(test_gtest test_gtest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test_gtest PRIVATE libTarget test_utils GTest::gtest_main)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(test_gtest)
```

Finally, when building `test_handcrafted.cpp` we can also check its dependencies `ldd test_handcrafted`:

> ```
> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdaa561000)
> libTarget.so => <path to repo dir>/lib/libTarget.so (0x00007ff7ab7ab000)
> ../lib/libDependencyLevel1.so (0x00007ff7ab76d000)
> ../lib/libDependencyLevel2.so (0x00007ff7ab612000)
> libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff7ab3e5000)
> libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff7ab294000)
> libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff7ab279000)
> libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff7ab087000)
> libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff7ab064000)
> libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff7ab05e000)
> ./libDependencyLevel2.so => not found
> libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff7ab040000)
> libjpeg.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007ff7aafbb000)
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff7ac01b000)
> ```

## Unsuccessful solution attempts

Here is a list of things I have tried without success to solve the issue:

- `target_link_libraries` on **test_project/CMakeLists.txt**

```
target_link_libraries(libDependencyLevel1 PUBLIC libDependencyLevel2) # INTERFACE and PRIVATE specifiers were also evaluated
```

- `link_directories` on **test_project/CMakeLists.txt**

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

## Reasoning and questions

According to the error message shown in the beginning of this post, the build system is not finding the shared libraries needed when GTest is used. But why is this happening? And why not using GTest solves the linking error, even if the IMPORTED SHARED libraries are imported in the same way for building both executables?

Finally, what can I do to solve the building issue when using GTest?

Comment: Is it possible to do `target_link_libraries(libDependencyLevel1 libDependencyLevel2)` instead of `add_dependencies`? Maybe that could resolve the issue? I don't actually know. But [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) is just for build ordering, and doesn't have any meaning for linkage.

Comment: I have added to the question a list of solutions I have tried so far without success. I agree that `add_dependecies` does not make any effect in the set-up I have described.

Comment: If `libDependencyLevel1` needs to use things from `libDependencyLevel2`, then  `target_link_libraries(libDependencyLevel1 INTERFACE libDependencyLevel2)` wouldn't work, because `INTERFACE` means that the "user" of `libDependencyLevel1` needs things from `libDependencyLevel2`, but `libDependencyLevel1` itself does not. Have you tried `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE`? I suggest reading [the `target_link_libraries`docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: Yes, I have also tried PUBLIC and PRIVATE. Question updated to mention it,